# How to access custom Token header added in Asp.Net Web Api response from Angular JS application?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

```
    //My login method is as follows, which takes credentials and validates them against a db table entries
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/login")]
    public IHttpActionResult Authenticate([FromBody]LoginModel credentials)
    {
        IHttpActionResult result;
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        TokenModel tokenInfo;
        var userId = (from n in _data.Users
                      where n.id == credentials.id && n.Password == credentials.Password
                      select n.id).FirstOrDefault().ToString();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
        {
            //Following mehtod generates a token and stores it in db for further usage
            tokenInfo = tokenFunctions.GenerateToken(userId);
            if (tokenInfo != null)
            {
                //Creating response message with custom headers info
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, userId);
                response.Headers.Add("Token", tokenInfo.AuthToken);
                response.Headers.Add("TokenExpiry", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthTokenExpiry"]);
                response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Token");
            }
            else
            {
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            }

            result = ResponseMessage(response);
            return result;
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }
```

When I am accessing the above method through fiddler, I am able to see Token and TokenExpiry headers under "Miscellaneous" section. But when I am trying to access this method from angular JS application, I am not able to see Token/TokenExpiry headers in headers parameter of $http.post() call back method.
Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue? Your reply helps me a lot.

Comment: where is the token stored? in local storage of browser? What i have done before was after i get the response from API i saved it in local storage using `LocalStorageModule` service so everytime I request access to api server I implemented an interceptor to retrieve the token from the local storage and append the token to the header.

Comment: I am new to Angular JS and I just wanted to print the token into console using $log.info. Currently I am not using localStorage service and interceptor. Will implement this solution and check. Thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9as2ac3d/ this is my login implementation nevermind for the html part